# Matlab - "Buttord" function returns negative order

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a problem with the buttord function, I guess I'm not getting how it works. I'm passing a few parameters and getting a negative order for the filter. How is this possible? I'm building an analog low pass filter with a pass band ending at 1500Hz and a stop band beginning at 2000Hz. The ripple requirements are in dB, not sure if it changes anything. I've been looking at the Matlab doc and can't find what's wrong with the code.

This is my code:

```
rbp = 0.10; %pass band ripple requierement 
rbs = 0.05; %stop band ripple

fp = 1500; %pass band freq
fs = 2000; %stop band freq

Wp = 2*pi*fp; % change to rad/sec
Ws = 2*pi*fs;

[N, Wn] = buttord(Wp,Ws,rbp,rbs,'s') %yields N = -1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrongly interpreting `rbs` as stop band ripple. Actually it represents *stop band minimum attenuation*, and thus it should have a much higher value. For example, setting .`rbs=20` (dB) gives `N=15`.

From `help buttord`:

> ```
> [N, Wn] = BUTTORD(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs) returns the order N of the lowest 
> order digital Butterworth filter that loses no more than Rp dB in 
> the passband and has at least Rs dB of attenuation in the stopband.  
> Wp and Ws are the passband and stopband edge frequencies, normalized 
> from 0 to 1 (where 1 corresponds to pi radians/sample).
> ```